# Regular expression to match a value, optionally enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: regex

Someone help me out with a regular expression please.

What I want to match:

```
="..."
='...'
=...
="...'..."
='..."...'
```

but not:

```
="...'
='..."
```

I want to match a value, optionally enclosed in one of two parenthesis types (" or ').
Both side should be terminated by the same type of parenthesis or nothing. The value itself may not contain parenthesis of the type it is opened or closed with.
If it lacks outer parenthesis, it may not contain any parenthesis. I have come this far:

```
\=[\x22\x27]{0,1}([^\x22\x27]*?)[\x22\x27]{0,1}$
```

`\x22` is `"` and `\x27` is `'`
`\=` and `$` is just for clarification. The actual borders are defined differently.

The 1st problem is, that the latter `[\x22\x27]{0,1}` should be equal to the initial `[\x22\x27]{0,1}`
2nd problem is, that the middle term `[^\x22\x27]` should be the negation of what the outer terms evaluate to.

Comment: I tried to explain several approaches in my answer, please clarify which flavor you are using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using Powershell Core 7.2 along with the 'Select-String' function. I think it's called .NET regex. I want to parse html tag attribute values. Hence, I've run into more problems: optional white spaces between the = and the optional opening parenthesis; and values without parenthesis will terminate with a white space or a >. Your answer: It think it is the most comprehensive. However, for the practical purpose of my question, understandability and maintainance, lmd's answer seems much more to the point. So I have a dilema of choosing the 'accepted' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=(?:([\x22\x27])(?=.*\1$))?((?:(?!\1).)*?)\1?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FqBX13/2).
*Details*:

- `=` - a `=` char (it should not be escaped)
- `(?:([\x22\x27])(?=.*\1$))?` - an optional occurrence of either a `'` or `"` char captured into Group 1 (`\1`) that is followed with any string of non-linebreak chars till the same char as in Group 1 at the end of the string
- `((?:(?!\1).)*?)` - Group 2: any char other than line break chars, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that is not equal to the Group 1 value
- `\1?` - Group 1 value (optional, for cases when Group 1 was not matched)
- `$` - end of string.

Another idea is using a conditional:

```
=([\x22\x27])?((?:(?!\1).)*?)(?(1)\1)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FqBX13/1).

Here, `(?(1)\1)` matches Group 1 value if Group 1 matched. Else, nothing is required at this location in the string.

**Note for ECMAScript regex flavor**

In this flavor (used in JavaScript, for example), group values that did not participate in the match are set to *an empty string*, not *null*, and as a consequence, the technique used in the first regex does not work for cases like `=123`.

In that case, you will *have to* reside to repetitions like

```
=(?:"(.*)"|'(.*)'|(.*))$
```

and using extra code logic define what group value you need to extract.

Comment: Great answer. For my use case, where I have optional parenthesis between the = and the optional opening parenthesis, and where a value can either terminate with a parenthesis of the same type or a white space or a >, I have expanded your conditional suggestion like this: =(?:\s*)?([\x22\x27])?((?:(?!\1).)*?)(?(1)\1|[\s>]) It now works (.NET regex) on all valid input strings, but it doesn't detect, if the opening and closing parenthesis differ. Good enough! [RegEx101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/zY5sss/1)

Comment: @jamacoe In this case, also consider [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/zY5sss/3), `=\s*(?:([\x22\x27])(?<val>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<val>\S+))`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative suggestion that requires fewer RegEx features:

```
=([^'"\n]*|(?:"[^"\n]*")|(?:'[^'\n]*'))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QqbbcQ/1

The boundaries `=` and `$` are just like your RegEx. The `(?:...)` are noncapturing groups. I've used `'` and `"` instead of the hex escapes for readability; you might have to escape them if your language doesn't provide raw string / RegEx literals.

At the core of the RegEx is the "choice" between the three possible "string literals":

- `[^'"\n]*`: String without delimiters, no quotes allowed;
- `"[^"\n]*"`: Double-quoted string;
- `'[^'\n]*'`: Single-quoted string

All character sets disallow (UNIX) newlines since string literals may not cross them; consider adding CR (`\r`) if you also want to forbid Mac (CR) & Windows (CRLF) newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
^=(?:(?:"([^"\r\n]+)")|(?:'([^'\r\n]+)')|(?:([^"'\r\n]+)))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bZc1YL/1